# Puppeteer won't load page

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm trying to use `puppeteer` to grab the requests from this page https://www.gsksaglik.com/internal-redirects.html but it seems that the page is not loaded at all because the browser won't close...

This is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('request', (data) => console.log(data));
  page.on('requestfailed', (data) => console.log(data));
  page.on('requestfinished', (data) => console.log(data));
  await page.goto('https://www.gsksaglik.com/internal-redirects.html');

  await browser.close();
})();
```

The events `page.request`, `page.requestfailed` and `requestfinised` are not fired

Does anyone know why this page isn't loaded?

Comment: Is program running without an error?

Comment: @ShubhamBatra it only gives this error `Error: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 30000ms exceeded'

Answer (score 0):

Give timeout mannually

```
await page.goto('https://www.gsksaglik.com/internal-redirects.html', {
            networkIdleTimeout: 5000,
            waitUntil: 'networkidle',
            timeout: 3000000
        });
```

for more reference check this link https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/782

Comment: I added this but now it will run until that timeout is reached ... the problem is that the `browser.close()` is never executed

Comment: I try following code in system const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function ab() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  page.on('request', (data) => console.log(data))
  page.on('requestfailed', (data) => console.log(data))
  page.on('requestfinished', (data) => console.log(data))
  await page.goto('https://www.gsksaglik.com/internal-redirects.html')
  await page.waitFor(10 * 10000)
  await browser.close()
}

ab()

Comment: It seems that it works when `headless` set to false, but it won't work with the `headless` option